# Cycle through data array and write out date to separate variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array of dates created from the function createDates. That works fine.

I then have a second for loop that should loop through the dates array and write the current date iteration into a final date variable called depDate. This depDate will be used as injected into a query string as a literal.

I would have expected the second for loop to log out one date per line. But thats not whats happened. Instead it just logs the last date in the array and I cannot work out why.

```js
//run this to generate the dates
let dates = [];

function createDates() {
  const listLength = 10; // days
  for (let i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
    let itemDate = new Date(); // starting today
    itemDate.setDate(itemDate.getDate() + i);
    dates.push(itemDate.toISOString());
  }
  return dates;
}

createDates();

let depDate = "";

const writeBody = () => {
  {
    for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++)
      //console.log(dates[i].slice(0, 10));
      //let depDate = dates[i].slice(0, 10);
      depDate = (dates[i].slice(0, 10));
    console.log([depDate]);
  }
}

writeBody();
```

Comment: The `for` loop has no brackets. So It's not processing as you might expect. Enclose the set of instructions with brackets. Also, it's just the final assignment. If you want the `depDate` to hold all the values, try something like `depDates += (dates[i].slice(0,10));`

Comment: Thank you both. @MesiRendón thanks for pointing that out. Case closed for now.

Comment: @Jbleasdale can you give an example of the final output? I imagined it as an HTML unordered list of date items for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote:

```
const writeBody = () => {
  {
    for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++)
      //console.log(dates[i].slice(0, 10));
      //let depDate = dates[i].slice(0, 10);
      depDate = (dates[i].slice(0, 10));
    console.log([depDate]);
  }
}
```

What you need is

```
const writeBody = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){
      //console.log(dates[i].slice(0, 10));
      //let depDate = dates[i].slice(0, 10);
      depDate = (dates[i].slice(0, 10));
    console.log([depDate]);
  }
}
```

Basically the for loop was only acting on the directly following statement, the console log was outside the loop.